# Subquery not showing all Results

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005

I have a subquery that takes in the item number from one table and uses it in a where clause to get a result from a main table. However, the subquery does not return the correct results. Here's the query and an example:

```
,(
 select TOP 1[UNITPRCE]FROM [NIMET].[dbo].[SOP10200]
 where [NIMET].[dbo].[SOP10200].ITEMNMBR=tblJobHold.ITEMNMBR 
 order by [NIMET].[dbo].[SOP10200].ReqShipDate desc
 )


ITEMNMBR                        Price
07-0008                         0.48000
20232001                        0.00000
22241457                        0.00000
67181001                        0.00000
LR56230-095                     2.36000
S-AF509                         0.59000
S24A7869A1                      0.00000
```

This returns some results, however, when I take one of the results that shows a zero and run it against the table, I get a result.

```
SELECT TOP 1 [UNITPRCE]FROM [NIMET].[dbo].[SOP10200]
  where ITEMNMBR='20232001'
  order by ReqShipDate desc

UNITPRCE
2.10000
```

Why is this result not being returned by the subquery?

Here's the whole query. its pretty short.

```
declare @start datetime,
@end datetime

set @start =convert(datetime,'10/13/2014')
set @end =convert(datetime,'10/14/2014')
SELECT  
      tblJobHold.[MANUFACTUREORDER_I]
      ,[HoldQty]
      ,tblJobHold.[ITEMNMBR]
      ,[ITEMDESC]
      ,[OnHoldByName]
      ,[OnHoldDate]
      ,[Problem]
      ,[Cause]
      ,[Resolution]
      ,[Notes]
     ,[ReleasedByName]
      ,[ReleasedDate]
     ,(SELECT TOP 1 [UNITPRCE]FROM [NIMET].[dbo].[SOP10200]
  where ITEMNMBR=tblJobHold.ITEMNMBR
  order by ReqShipDate desc)   
      FROM [NIMETData].[dbo].[tblJobHold]
  WHERE [ReleasedDate] >= @start AND [ReleasedDate] < @end
  and Resolution in ('NOT FOUND', 'SCRAP-NIMET','SCRAP-PIONEEER','SCRAP-PIONEER','SCRAP-CUSTOMER','REWORK')
```

SOP10200 hold the prices for each of the items based on last shipped date. I am trying to get the corresponding price from the latest date using the part number from the tblJobHold table. Both have matching part numbers.

**I added a second subquery from that table and it returns values on each instance. it seems ust the price one is broke**

```
,(SELECT TOP 1 [shipToName]
FROM [NIMET].[dbo].[SOP10200]
where ITEMNMBR=tblJobHold.ITEMNMBR 
order by ReqShipDate desc) as 'Ship To'
```

Comment: What datatypes are `[NIMET].[dbo].[SOP10200].ITEMNMBR` and `tblJobHold.ITEMNMBR`

Comment: There isn't enough info here, could you post the whole script?

Comment: `ITEMNMBR=tblJobHold.ITEMNMBR` looks ambiguous how about `(SELECT TOP 1 [UNITPRCE]FROM [NIMET].[dbo].[SOP10200] x where x.ITEMNMBR=tblJobHold.ITEMNMBR order by ReqShipDate desc)  `

Comment: No dice, sorry. thanks for the help though

Comment: I ran this query in an SSRS report and it came across correct. What does this mean?